# React click events on flowchart nodes in graphviz-react?

Tags: reactjs, graphviz

I'm trying out a few different methods for **rendering flowcharts in React**. So far I've gotten **mermaid** and **react-flow** working, and now I'm working on **graphviz**.

With mermaid, I could just add `click {nodeId} handleNodeClick` to each node to get it to capture node clicks, and with react-flow I could just add `onNodeClick = {handleNodeClick}` to the props of ReactFlow to capture node clicks.

However, I can't find any sort of comparable functionality in graphviz-react. I can use the graphviz attributes to add a URL to each node, that will open when the node is clicked (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/URL/), but that is the only click-related functionality I can find, and I suspect that using a link to update the js app is the wrong way to go.

Any suggestions? I'm guessing the solution involves adding an onclick attribute to each node as a sort of post-process step, but I don't know how to do that in React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. I added a useEffect(), which is effectively post-processing on the element, to go through and add the onclick event everywhere I want it, like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const graphElement = document.querySelector('div.flowchart');

    flowData.forEach((item) => {
        var e = graphElement.querySelector('#'+item.id);
        if(e) {
            e.onclick= function() { 
                SelectItemById(item.id); 
            };
        }
    });
  });
```

on the downside, this is SUPER SLOW, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it...

Comment: You should return a function from the useEffectHook which removes all the event handlers.  That's probably why it is slow as you are constantly adding more handlers without removing the old ones.